# How to resize columns of a table?

Tags: tables, french

I'm a beginner in Latex and I have used a table in my document. This is a part of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{ragged2e, ltablex, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\caption{: Les mesures de sentiment retenues par Brown et Cliff (2004)}
\begin{tabular}{|p{92pt}|p{136pt}|p{76pt}|p{558pt}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{189pt}|}{\textbf{Mesures du sentiment}\textsf{ }} & 
\textbf{Indicateur } \par \textbf{ou variable}& 
\textbf{Description} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{189pt}|}{\raisebox{-1.50ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{Mesures directes}\textsf{}}}& 
${SENT}^{a}$\textsf{}& 
Sentiment des investisseurs ``~amateurs~'' ou individuels issu de l'enqu\^{e}te de l'(AAII). \\
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{2}{|p{189pt}|}{} & 
${SENT}^{p}$\textsf{}& 
Sentiment des investisseurs professionnels issu de l'enqu\^{e}te de l'(II)\textsf{.} \\
\hline
\raisebox{-25.50ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{Mesures indirectes}}& 
\raisebox{-1.50ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{Performance du march\'{e}}}& 
${ARMS}_{t}$\textsf{}& 
Ratio de d\'{e}clin avanc\'{e} (voir 2.2.4)\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$\left( {HI} \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{HI} {LO}}} \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {LO} \right)$\textsf{}& 
D\'{e}note le ratio de nombre de valeurs faisant de nouveaux plus hauts par rapport aux nombre de valeurs faisant de nouveaux plus bas. Cet indicateur est \'{e}galement con\c{c}u pour saisir la force relative du march\'{e} \par \textsf{} \\
\cline{2-4} 
 & 
\raisebox{-6.00ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{Type d'activit\'{e} commerciale}}& 
$\Delta MARGIN$\textsf{}& 
D\'{e}note le pourcentage de variation de l'encours des pr\^{e}ts pour achats sur marge tel que rapport\'{e} par la R\'{e}serve f\'{e}d\'{e}rale. Cette mesure est souvent cit\'{e}e comme un indicateur haussier, car elle repr\'{e}sente les investisseurs utilisant de l'argent emprunt\'{e} pour investir.\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$\Delta SHORTIR$\textsf{}& 
La variation en pourcentage de l'int\'{e}r\^{e}t \`{a} court terme est visualis\'{e}e. Cette mesure est consid\'{e}r\'{e}e comme un indicateur baissier.\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$SORTSLS$\textsf{}& 
Le ratio des ventes \`{a} d\'{e}couvert sur le totale des ventes.\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$SPECIAL$\textsf{}& 
D\'{e}note le rapport des ventes \`{a} d\'{e}couvert des sp\'{e}cialistes ou professionnels au total des ventes \`{a} d\'{e}couvert\textsf{.}\textsf{ } \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$ODDLOT$\textsf{}& 
D\'{e}note le ratio des ordres de ventes de moins de cent titres sur les ordres d'achats de moins de cent titres. Ce ratio r\'{e}fl\`{e}te est une mesure baissi\`{e}re\textsf{.} \textsf{} \\
\cline{2-4} 
 & 
\raisebox{-6.00ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{Variables issues du march\'{e} d\'{e}riv\'{e}}}& 
Ratio $(Put/Call)$\textsf{}& 
Ratio d\'{e}j\`{a} avanc\'{e} traduisant le rapport entre le volume \'{e}chang\'{e} sur des calls/volume \'{e}chang\'{e} sur les puts. (voir 2.2.2)\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$FUT^{a}$ \par \textsf{}& 
\raisebox{-1.50ex}[0cm][0cm]{La CFTC (Commodities Futures Trading Commission) organisme assurant la r\'{e}gulation du march\'{e} d\'{e}riv\'{e} am\'{e}ricain rapporte chaque jour la variation de la position nette dans les contrats \`{a} terme standardis\'{e}s SPX par type d'op\'{e}rateur (sont consid\'{e}r\'{e}s comme ``~commercial traders~'' tout intervenant utilisant des contrats d'options ou futures pour couvrir des risques et ``~non- commercial traders~'' dans tous les autres cas). Ces donn\'{e}es sur les ``~non-commercial traders~''$FUT^{p}$comme indicateur du sentiment institutionnels et des ``~small traders~'' et$FUT^{a}$comme approximation du sentiment des investisseurs individuels. Selon la d\'{e}finition de la CFTC, les ``~non-commercial traders~'' sont essentiellement des professionnels du march\'{e}, \`{a} l'exclusion des soci\'{e}t\'{e}s financi\`{e}res et commerciales\textsf{.}} \\
\cline{3-3} 
 & 
 & 
$FUT^{p}$\textsf{}& 
 \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$MKTVANE$\textsf{}& 
Est un pr\'{e}tendu pr\'{e}dicteur haussier du comportement des march\'{e}s \`{a} terme qui ``est calcul\'{e} en suivant les recommandations d'achat et de vente de principaux conseillers du march\'{e}~''\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$VOL_{t}$& 
Mesure de la volatilit\'{e} attendue par rapport \`{a} la volatilit\'{e} constat\'{e}e, donn\'{e} par~: \par $TRIAL RESTRICTION$ \par O\`{u} VIX repr\'{e}sente la volatilit\'{e} des options de l'indice S{\&}P 100 et SIG, la volatilit\'{e} r\'{e}alis\'{e}e calcul\'{e}e \`{a} partir des donn\'{e}es Open-High-Low-Close de l'indice S{\&}P100. Ainsi, un VOL positif mesure une volatilit\'{e} anticip\'{e}e \'{e}l\'{e}v\'{e} et peut \^{e}tre interpr\'{e}t\'{e} comme indicateur baissier.\textsf{} \\
\cline{2-4} 
 & 
\raisebox{-4.50ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{Autres indicateurs du sentiment}}& 
$CEFDT$& 
D\'{e}note la d\'{e}cote des fonds ferm\'{e} (voir 2.2.3)\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$TRIAL RESTRICTION$& 
D\'{e}note les achats nets de fonds communs de placement. Neal et Wheatley (1998) estiment que cela est utile pour pr\'{e}dire la prime des faibles valeurs par rapport aux grands valeurs.\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$FUNDFLOW$& 
Est la proportion des actifs du fonds d\'{e}tenus en esp\`{e}ces. Brown et Cliff (2004) pr\'{e}sument que les liquidit\'{e}s d'un fonds auront une relation n\'{e}gative avec ses optimisme \`{a} propos du march\'{e}.\textsf{} \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$FUNDCASH$& 
Rendement du premier jour de cotation des actions introduites en bourse (IPORET) et (IPON) est le nombre d'introduction nombre (Ibbotson and Ritter (1995)). \\
\cline{2-4} 
 & 
\raisebox{-1.50ex}[0cm][0cm]{\textbf{Variables de contr\^{o}le}\textsf{ }}& 
$R_{BIG}$& 
Rendement des grosses valeurs, ainsi que leurs retards temporels. \\
\cline{3-4} 
 & 
 & 
$R_{SOB}$& 
Est la partie des rendements des faibles valeurs orthogonalis\'{e}s \`{a} $R_{BIG}$\textsf{.}\textsf{} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{center}
```

How can I resize my table?

Comment: Please add a minimal code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Off-topic: The `latexsym` is seriously deprecated. Don't use it. Employ the `amssymb` package instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you use a `longtable` to typeset the tabular material over two pages. I would also like to suggest that you give the material a much more open "look", mainly by omitting all vertical bars and employing very few, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. Using whitespace can be every bit as effective to create visual "separation".

Since you're writing in French, I would further like to suggest that you use the `babel` package (with `french` as the language option) and the `csquotes` package (with option `french=guillemets`) to typeset quoted material in a way that respects French typographic traditions. Be sure to load the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages with suitable options in order to input and output "accented" characters directly.

To typeset variable names in italics, don't use plain-math mode. Instead, use math-italic lettering, as is performed in the following example. The following screenshot shows just the first 15 or so rows of the `longtable`. Note that linebreaks can occur automatically, as needed, in all three columns. (I eliminated 1 column relative to your table design.)

Note that I cleaned up your code too; I trust you're fine with that. For sure, inputting `(HI/LO)` must be a lot easier than `\left( {HI} \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{HI} {LO}}} \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {LO} \right)$\textsf{}` is, right? I've also deleted all instances of `\textsf{}` and `\textsf{ }`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose suitable page parameters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % enter accented characters directly
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % or some other suitable text and math font family
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array,
            ragged2e,booktabs,longtable}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes} % to typeset quoted material

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % variable names

\newlength\lena \settowidth\lena{Mesures du sentiment\,}
\newlength\lenb \settowidth\lenb{Ratio (Put/Call)\,}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}
     P{\lena\hangafter=1\hangindent1.5em} % automatic hanging indentation
     P{\lenb}
     P{\dimexpr3.4\lenb\relax} @{}}

%% define the headers and footers

\caption{Les mesures de sentiment retenues par Brown et Cliff (2004)} 
\label{tab1} \\
\toprule
Mesures du sentiment & 
Indicateur ou variable & 
Description \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\small\tablename\ \ref{tab1}, continué}\\[0.25ex]
\toprule
Mesures du sentiment & 
Indicateur ou variable & 
Description \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\small\em voir page suivante}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% now the body of table

Mesures directes 

   & $\vn{SENT}^a$ 
   & Sentiment des investisseurs \enquote{amateurs} ou individuels issu de l'enquête de l'(AAII). \\
\addlinespace 
   & $\vn{SENT}^p$
   & Sentiment des investisseurs professionnels issu de l'enquête de l'(II). \\[1.5ex]

Mesures indirectes \\[0.75ex]

\hspace{1.5em}Performance du marché& 
   $\vn{ARMS}_{t}$
   & Ratio de déclin avancé (voir~2.2.4) \\
   \addlinespace  
   & $\vn{(HI/LO)}$ 
   & Dénote le ratio de nombre de valeurs faisant de nouveaux plus hauts par rapport aux nombre de valeurs faisant de nouveaux plus bas. Cet indicateur est également con\c{c}u pour saisir la force relative du marché. \\
\addlinespace  
\hspace{1.5em}Type d'activité commerciale 
    & $\vn{\Delta MARGIN}$
    & Dénote le pourcentage de variation de l'encours des prêts pour achats sur marge tel que rapporté par la Réserve fédérale. Cette mesure est souvent citée comme un indicateur haussier, car elle représente les investisseurs utilisant de l'argent emprunté pour investir. \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{\Delta SHORTIR}$
    & La variation en pourcentage de l'intérêt à court terme est visualisée. Cette mesure est considérée comme un indicateur baissier. \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{SORTSLS}$
    & Le ratio des ventes à découvert sur le totale des ventes. \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{SPECIAL}$
    & Dénote le rapport des ventes à découvert des spécialistes ou professionnels au total des ventes à découvert. \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{ODDLOT}$
    & Dénote le ratio des ordres de ventes de moins de cent titres sur les ordres d'achats de moins de cent titres. Ce ratio réflète est une mesure baissière. \\
\addlinespace 
\hspace{1.5em}Variables issues du marché dérivé
    & Ratio (Put\slash Call)
    & Ratio déjà avancé traduisant le rapport entre le volume échangé sur des calls\slash volume échangé sur les puts. (voir~2.2.2) \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{FUT}^a$ 
    & La CFTC (Commodities Futures Trading Commission) organisme assurant la régulation du marché dérivé américain rapporte chaque jour la variation de la position nette dans les contrats à terme standardisés SPX par type d'opérateur (sont considérés comme \enquote{commercial traders} tout intervenant utilisant des contrats d'options ou futures pour couvrir des risques et \enquote{non-commercial traders} dans tous les autres cas). Ces données sur les \enquote{non-commercial traders} $\vn{FUT}^{p}$ comme indicateur du sentiment institutionnels et des \enquote{small traders} et $\vn{FUT}^{a}$ comme approximation du sentiment des investisseurs individuels. Selon la définition de la CFTC, les \enquote{non-commercial traders} sont essentiellement des professionnels du marché, à l'exclusion des sociétés financières et commerciales. \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{FUT}^p$
    & \\  % something missing?
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{MKTVANE}$
    & Est un prétendu prédicteur haussier du comportement des marchés à terme qui \enquote{est calculé en suivant les recommandations d'achat et de vente de principaux conseillers du marché} \\
\addlinespace  
    & $\vn{VOL}_t$
    & Mesure de la volatilité attendue par rapport à la volatilité constatée, donné par: \par 
    $\vn{TRIAL}$ $\vn{RESTRICTION}$ \par 
    Où VIX représente la volatilité des options de l'indice S\&P100 et SIG, la volatilité réalisée calculée à partir des données Open-High-Low-Close de l'indice S\&P100. Ainsi, un VOL positif mesure une volatilité anticipée élévé et peut être interprété comme indicateur baissier. \\
\addlinespace  
\hspace{1.5em}Autres indicateurs du sentiment 
    & $\vn{CEFDT}$
    & Dénote la décote des fonds fermé (voir~2.2.3) \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{TRIAL}$ $\vn{RESTRICTION}$
    & Dénote les achats nets de fonds communs de placement. Neal et Wheatley (1998) estiment que cela est utile pour prédire la prime des faibles valeurs par rapport aux grands valeurs. \\
\addlinespace  
    & $\vn{FUNDFLOW}$
    & Est la proportion des actifs du fonds détenus en espèces. Brown et Cliff (2004) présument que les liquidités d'un fonds auront une relation négative avec ses optimisme à propos du marché. \\
\addlinespace 
    & $\vn{FUNDCASH}$
    & Rendement du premier jour de cotation des actions introduites en bourse (IPORET) et (IPON) est le nombre d'introduction nombre (Ibbotson and Ritter, 1995). \\
\addlinespace 
\hspace{1.5em}Variables de contrôle
    & $\vn{R_{BIG}}$
    & Rendement des grosses valeurs, ainsi que leurs retards temporels. \\
\addlinespace  
    & $\vn{R_{SOB}}$
    & Est la partie des rendements des faibles valeurs orthogonalisés à $\vn{R_{BIG}}$. \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico for you help. yes i write in french and I'm economist too.

Comment: @nino - Vivent les économistes! Do please promise, though, that you'll never again write something as atrocious as `\left( {HI} \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{HI} {LO}}} \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {LO} \right)$\textsf{}`. :-)

Comment: @nino - On a more serious note, observe the specification `P{\dimexpr3.4\lenb\relax}` for the third column. Depending on the page size parameters of your document, you may have to adjust the scalar multiplier `3.4` to make the `longtable` environment fill up the available width of the textblock.